# Advanced Level Chemistry Book Recommendation

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

I have a test comming up on Chemistry in Advanced Level and I sincerly ask for a book recommendation for chemistry. I already got the book chemistry by Ramond Chang. And I am pretty near to the exam. What I really want is a book with Lesson and Questions related to that specific lesson book.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "lesson book"?  Do you mean you want a workbook for the Chang text?

Comment: Yes. I want the work book and also a book that explains the lesson like Chang's.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37303/4945

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=2017277) are a few recommendations for A-level chemistry, made by fellow students such as yourself. TSR is a good student resource for A-level prep since there is are masses of students talking about the same topics.

([Zumdahl](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1285199030) is a good general chemistry textbook as well, with quite the number of practice problems. However it is a full-fledged textbook you probably don't need a few days before an exam.)

Answer (score 0):

Try 'Advanced Chemistry by Philip Mathews ' - a red large book.
That explain very much in chemistry for advanced level.